# JS consecutive form downloads

Tags: javascript, browser

I am having a problem with downloading some reports. User has the master entity, then selects from the list of details. When user clicks a button, I group details by their master, and send the request to the server, where the SSRS report is created and returned in the MS Word format, for each master. The request is in the form of

```
http://url/to/action/?masterID=guid&detailIDs=guid1,guid2,guid3
```

CUrrently this is being done via iframes

```
function DownloadFile(url) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var id = 'iframe_' + Math.random() * 1000000000000000000;
    iframe.id = id;
    iframe.src = url;
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    //removes window
    window.setTimeout(function () { $('#' + id).remove(); }, 9000);
}
```

Which is problem when user selects somewhere around 50 details from grid (url too long). I tried changing the DownloadFile function, so it takes url, and data to post to server, but when iterating through the array, and doing consecutive form posts, but only first succeedes, and others don't pass through.

I tried also iterating through document.forms and submitting them, but it failed as well.

Is there a way to enable this functionality, or is it prohibited by browser's engine?

Comment: why do you want to do multiple post request?
Can you change your action to take all parameters in one call?

Comment: I don't think that's the case. What he wants to do is be able to take a list of all the parameters and create one response, but the URL has a length limit. Right?

Comment: The problem is with our users basically. One of the options was to download all files in one zip file, but we can't do that because, well, we aren't sure they'll know how to use zip files :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a HTTP POST method to send the data to the server that is generating the results.

`url = 'http://url/to/action/?masterID=' + masterID;`
`detailIDs = [guid1,guid2,guid3];`

```
function DownloadFile(url, detailIDs) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var id = 'iframe_' + Math.random() * 1000000000000000000;
    iframe.id = id; 
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    //pseudo code, intention is to create a form and submit it from within the iframe. 
    iframe.submitForm(url, detailIDs);        

    //removes window
    window.setTimeout(function () { $('#' + id).remove(); }, 9000);
}
```

[See: how to create a form using js.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001830/creating-and-submitting-a-form-with-javascript)