# How to submit form created in javascript.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Here I have made a form in javascript, Now I want to sumbit this form but I dont know how to submit this form.

Here is my little code any one can help me.?

```
<script>
    $("button#pass_data").on('click',function(e){                   

        var p_name = $(this).attr('value');

        '<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>teq" method="post" id="submit_papername">'+
            '<input typ="text" name="pip" value="'+p_name+'">'+
        '</form>'
        //document.getElementById('data_send').value == p_name;
        console.log('p_name');
        document.getElementById('submit_papername').submit();
        //alert(p_name);

});
</script>
```

I want to submit this newaly created form **submit_papername** , How can I do this.?

when I run above code it show me error like below.

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Why make the form at all? Just send an AJAX request. If you need to do it this way then you have to append the `form` to the DOM first.

Comment: Your form is not a form. Its just an anonymous string. Its not part of any DOM, so there is no "submitting" it.

Comment: You haven't actually made the form. You've defined a string, but you haven't done anything with it.

Comment: I have some problem with ajax so I must need this

Comment: You have not appended String in DOM hence there is no `form` in DOM tree..

Comment: Error occurred because you created that form string but did not append to HTML. That's why that error occurring.

Comment: What is the problem using AJAX?

Comment: @Rayon yes buddy thanks for this. I forget to append this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating and submitting a form with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001830/creating-and-submitting-a-form-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append element first `$('body').append(app);`.Then only perform the form submit

```
$("button#pass_data").on('click',function(e){                   

            var p_name = $(this).attr('value');

            var app = '<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>teq" method="post" id="submit_papername">'+
                '<input typ="text" name="pip" value="'+p_name+'">'+
            '</form>'
             $('body').append(app);
            //document.getElementById('data_send').value == p_name;
            console.log('p_name');
            document.getElementById('submit_papername').submit();
            //alert(p_name);

    });
```

Comment: yes I forget to append this. Like I say it in above comments. Still I am accepting your answer. anyway thanks for help