# Stripe custom checkout - form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, stripe-payments

I'm trying out the Stripe API & functions, but I am twisting my head around this one issue - how to submit a form after the (test) payment is successful?

Here's my current code:

```
<script>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'pk_test_mykey',
        image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
        locale: 'sv',
        token: function(token) {
            // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
            // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
        }
    });


    document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        stripe_spots = document.getElementById("spots").value;
        stripe_total = (stripe_spots) * 70;
        // Open Checkout with further options:
        handler.open({
            name: 'Revy!',
            description: stripe_spots + " platser",
            zipCode: true,
            currency: 'sek',
            amount: stripe_total * 100
        });

        e.preventDefault();
     });

     // Close Checkout on page navigation:
     window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
         handler.close();
     });
 </script>
```

Where or when am I supposed to submit the form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You submit the form using the token callback function update your handle like so

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: 'pk_test_mykey',
image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
locale: 'sv',
token: function (token) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/checkout.php',
        data: {stripeToken: token.id, stripeEmail: token.email},
        success: function (data) {
            //handle success response here
        },
        error: function(data){
            //handle error response here
        }
    });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**After retrieving Stripe TOKEN you should send your data to your server including TOKEN to make Stripe Charge or create Subscription**

[Here is an example tutorial to create Customer for Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/subscription-signup#creating-the-signup-form-using-checkout)

Comment: The question here was regarding Stripe "Custom" Checkout. The word "Custom" is key here. The linked example creates a Stripe "Simple" Checkout. Very different from the Stripe "Custom" Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Editing my earlier answer, because I've got it working so I can share the code snippet. (Was struggling with the same problem when I discovered this.)

Here is my solution. It works. This assumes your next page is named "PaymentComplete.php". Edit accordingly.

```
token: function(token) {
// You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
// Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
var form = document.createElement("form");
var tokenPassed = document.createElement("input");
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "PaymentComplete.php";
tokenPassed.value = token.id;
tokenPassed.name = "token";
form.appendChild(tokenPassed);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}
```

There may be a better way of doing it, but this works for me.

Source: [creating and submitting a form with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001830/creating-and-submitting-a-form-with-javascript/13001878)