# MultiStep form Client validation using Jquery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a requirement of building an mvc based multi-step application form that will have 4 steps:-
Basic-details, Contact-details, Operations-details, vehicle details.

Basic includes-Basic user information like name ,dob.

Contact- Address, Mailing Address, Shipping Address, Phone

Operations-Some Yes/no questions with reasoning

Vehicle-This is a section to add multiple vehicle details.

Every section is segregated with a div. I need to **validate 1 section & only then move to the next section** i.e.  basic details section when filled ,will be validated & only then move to contact details section for which I need client side validation.

I need to use Jquery validation  plugin rather than having custom validation but the issue with jquery validation is it works with a complete form & in my case the validation is one section at a time rather than a single form.
Any input for the above will be helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use, one form for each section for js validation. Then when you submit or you are in the last section. and click submit, you manually build a form and submit it to the client side.

Here is an example on how to build and submit form via js.
this example is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001830/creating-and-submitting-a-form-with-javascript/13001878)

```
function autoLogIn(un, pw) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");  

    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "login.php";   

    element1.value=un;
    element1.name="un";
    form.appendChild(element1);  

    element2.value=pw;
    element2.name="pw";
    form.appendChild(element2);

    form.submit();
}
```

There is also other example you could check out here, with [Multiple step form with jQuery validation](https://www.djaodjin.com/blog/jquery-multi-step-validation.blog.html)

Comment: :Thank you very much for the input. This is what i was looking for. I am able to builld a new form on the last section.